# Como manter uma ViewBag para todas as Controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou desenvolvendo em ASPNET MVC 4 com Razor.

Fiz a página de login e está tudo ok.

Após o login, a famosa frase "Bem vindo FLAVIO" está sendo retornada com sucesso, via ViewBag.

Como estou fazendo um redirect, então estou fazendo desta forma, na Action LogOn:

```
User user = _repository.AutenticarUsuario(f["username"], f["password"]);
TempData["usuario"] = user.fname;
return Redirect("/Home/Index");
```

Lá na VIEW /Home/Index, eu tenho este código:

```
ViewBag.user = ViewBag.usuario;
```

E então o nome do usuário está sendo mostrado com sucesso.

O problema é que se eu entro em algum outro link no sistema, o nome do usuário vai pro espaço!

Como faço para que o nome do usuário persista para todas as actions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faça um `ActionFilter`:

```
public class MeuActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ViewBag.User = // coloque aqui a informação do usuário

        this.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Depois basta marcar o *Controller*:

```
[MeuActionFilter]
public class MeuController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

Mais informações? [Leia aqui](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs).

Comment: Obrigado. Esta sua resposta me fez pesquisar sobre ActionFilters e vi que tenho muito mais opções, como registrar o valor que necessito globalmente para evitar que eu fique tendo que adicionar o "marcador" do filtro em cada Controller, entre outras várias opções.